# How Can to control threads in testing by Espresso 2?

Tags: android, multithreading, testing, android-espresso

I have Test by library Espresso 2:

```
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
...

@LargeTest
public class MyTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {

    public MyTest() {
        super(MyActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        ...
        getActivity();
    }

public void testOne() {
  ...
}

public void testTwo() {
  ...
}

}
```

This test uses two threads:

Thread_1 in method setUp(),
then Thread_2 working in my Activity - method `onStart() {... app.setScreenController(this);...}`
then Thread_1 in method testOne(), so one test was successfully completed,

then Thread_1 in method setUp(),
then Thread_2 working in my Activity - method `onStop() {... app.setScreenController(null);...}`
then Thread_1 in method testTwo(), so two test throws NullPointerException :(, because I set controller null in method onStop. But!!! - Espresso must be starting method onStart after onStop!!!

And If I run my project in Debug: espresso starting onStop(), then starting onStart(), and I have not NullPointerException. Why? :(
How can to control these threads in espresso?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? What's the error message. Don't use threads, it should just work with the setup you posted. So the problem is likely something else.

Comment: First starting the method setUp(), then onStart() is started in Activity - I set same parameters in onStart(), then test_One is started, then setUp() is started, and main! - then onStop() is started in Activity - I set null same parameters, then onStart() must be started, but test_Two is started - so I have NullPointerException, Because in onStart() I set same object, and in onStop() I set null it object. If I run this two tests in Debug - All good!, But If I simply run - tests are not work :(

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, but what you are describing should work, as long as you only have one activity. After running a test, espresso is unwinding the activity stack by finishing all activities in reverse order. But this unwinding implementation in Espresso is broken, which will prevent it from working with multiple activities. There is a bug filed together with instructions for how to work around it here: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=66 Comment #4 may help you.